# XLST select by value of attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

The XML structure is as below. I need to assign text of  to variable currentAddress_Street1 if Address type = "C".

```
<Addresses>
    <Address Type="P">
      <Street1>220 State Street</Street1>
      <Street2 />
      <City>HATTIESBURG</City>
      <State>MS</State>
      <ZipCode>12354</ZipCode>
      <Country />
     </Address>

    <Address Type="C">
      <Street1>1000 </Street1>
      <Street2 />
      <City>Jackson</City>
      <State>MS</State>
      <ZipCode>12354</ZipCode>
      <Country />
     </Address>
```

Below is my try. Very new to XLST.Can someone help modify it?

```
  <xsl:variable name="currentAddress_Street1">
<xsl:value-of select="//Addresses/Address/Street1[Address/@Type='C']" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing the attribute of the parent node, so you have to specify that in your predicate, since it operates on the context of `Street1`.

```
//Addresses/Address/Street1[parent::Address/@Type='C']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way it can be done is by putting the predicate on the `Address` like so

```
//Addresses/Address[@Type='C']/Street1
```

As you can see it's much cleaner and is easier to identify what you are trying to do.